# html5 filereader - how can i manually create a file list?

Tags: jquery, html, filereader, filelist

i will programming a image uploader with trash icon.

how can i create a filelist with jQuery for each loop?

the standardcode for html5 filereader works:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
    files = evt.target.files || evt.dataTransfer.files;
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        reader = new FileReader();
        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
            return function (e) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.onload = function () {
                    $('#output').append("<img data-rotate='270' src='" + e.target.result + "'>");
                }
                img.src = e.target.result;
            };
        })(f);
        //Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
```

the upload funcion:

```
function upload_files() {
    //i need a new filelist with jquery $('#allpicturediv').each(function(){
    //newfiles .....
    for (var i = 0, f; f = newfiles[i]; i++) {
        upload_file_now(f);
    }
}

function upload_file_now(f) {
    //Do the actual uploading
    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.open('PUT', '...../upload.php', true);
    //Send the file details along with the request
    ..........
    XHR.send(f);
}
```

the problem is, when the user remove a picture, is the filelist not more current.

i think i need a script to create a new file list, in the `upload_files()` function.

how can solved this problem? i have already headache.

Answer (score 0):

i created this code and it functions fine.

First lets create a little function to determinate the type of file selected:

```
function openFile(file) {
    var extension = file.substr( (file.lastIndexOf('.') +1) ).toLowerCase();;
    switch(extension) {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'png':
        case 'gif':
            return 'image'; 
        break;                        
        case 'zip':
        case 'rar':
            return 'zip'; 
        break;
        case 'xls':
        case 'xlsx':
        case 'ppt':
        case 'pptx':
        case 'doc':
        case 'docx':
        case 'pst':
            return 'office'; 
        break;
        case 'pdf':
            return 'pdf';
        default:
            return 'other'; 
    }
};
```

We'll call it later.

Then the event of de Input type 'file', i added comments in almost every line:

```
var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL; 
         $("div.upload input[type='file']").change(function() { // Every time we selected a file

            var input = $(this)[0];
            for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) { // We run a "for" loop for each element

                var thisClass = openFile(input.files[i].name); // We run the functione above to know the type of file


                if(thisClass != 'image')  { // if there's not an image, we create anything else

                    // On thi example we create a <p> with the class of de element (PDF, XLSX, DOCX, Etc)
                    // Later with css we can create an icon based on the class
                    $(this).closest('.upload_container' ).find(".fileName").append('<p class="' + openFile(input.files[i].name) +'">'+input.files[i].name+'</p>');  
                }else { // But if there's an image then lets do this:

                    var chosen = this.files[i]; //We select the file 
                    var image = new Image(); // Create an new image

                    var imageName = input.files[i].name; // Get the name of the file

                    image.onload = function() { // CREATE STEP 2.- When we creat the image do anything you want
                        //alert('Width:'+this.width +' Height:'+ this.height+' '+ Math.round(chosen.size/1024)+'KB');

                        var imageWidth = parseInt(this.width); 
                        var imageHeight = parseInt(this.height);


                        if(imageWidth < minWidth || imageHeight < minHeight) {

                            // We can send alerts or something for the size.

                            alert("La imágen " + imageName + " es más pequeña de lo requerido. Se requiere una imagen con un ancho mínimo de " + minWidth + "px y un alto mínimo de " + minHeight + "px." );
                        }

                    };

                     image.src = url.createObjectURL(chosen); // We are creating the image so go to CREATE STEP 2

                    // Now we create an div width the background of the image created before
                    $(this).closest('.upload_container' ).find(".fileName").append('<div class="thumbnailImage" style="background-image:url(' + image.src +');"></div>');                       
                }

            }

         });
```

I hope it can help you!

Comment: hmm has you me misunderstood? sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.chatle.de/P1.jpg

this works good. i will remove a picture:

http://www.chatle.de/P2.jpg

and click on upload (hochladen).

the problem is, the 2th picture (from P1.jpg) is yet in the filelist. the filelist has a mode "readonly". also need a new list for the uploadfunction. (upload_files()) (and i will add other informations (comment for the picture, rotate number ...)

```
for (var i = 0, f; f = newfiles[i]; i++) {
    upload_file_now(f,myaddstrings);
}
```